# var initalization at the time of declaration in scala

Tags: scala

I am confused with following initialization

```
var in = None: Option[FileInputStream]
```

however what I know is that

```
var varName : type = _ // default value initialization
var varName : type = someValue // other than default intitalization
```

but what is

```
 var in = None: Option[FileInputStream]
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//  [name]  =  [value] : [type]
var in      =  None    : Option[FileInputStream] 

// can equivalently be written as: 
var in: Option[FileInputStream] = None
```

This creates a variable of type `Option[FileInputStream]`, with the initial value `None`.
To learn more about Scala's `Option` type, see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option

Comment: Thanks,I just tried it in REPL and found the same . Since Scala has vast syntex so I thought it would have some specific meaning

Answer (score 4):

This is called a *type ascription* and the resulting expression is called a [*typed expression*](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#typed-expressions). It, well, ascribes a type to an expression:

```
expr: Type
```

means "treat `expr` as if it had `Type`".

For example:

```
1
// Int

1: Float
// Float
```

Obviously, the expression needs to conform to the type that is ascribed to it.

The most widely used example of type ascription is probably the `_*` pseudo-type, which unpacks a `Seq` into a series of arguments:

```
def sumNums(nums: Int*) = nums.sum

sumNums()
//=> 0

sumNums(1)
//=> 1

sumNums(1, 2)
//=> 3

sumNums(Seq(1, 2))
// error: type mismatch;
// found   : Seq[Int]
// required: Int
//           sumNums(Seq(1, 2))
//                      ^

sumNums(Seq(1, 2): _*)
//=> 3
```

In your particular case, I find it questionable to ascribe a type to an expression just to get the type inferencer to infer the correct type, when you could just as well have declared the correct type to begin with:

```
var in: Option[FileInputStream] = None
```

With regards to your comments:

> however what I know is that
>
> ```
> var varName : type = _ // default value initialization
> var varName : type = someValue // other than default intitalization
> ```

You can also leave out the type:

```
var varName = someValue
```

In this case, the type is inferred from the expression `someValue`.

```
var varName = _
```

Obviously, this cannot work: the type is inferred from the expression, but the value of the expression is inferred from the type. Therefore, this is not allowed.

Your example uses the form with inferred type:

```
var in = someExpression
```

So, the type of `in` is inferred from the type of `someExpression`.

Now, if we said

```
var in = None
```

then the type inferred for `in` would be `None.type`, i.e. the singleton type of the `None` object. But that doesn't make sense: why would we have a `var`, i.e. a variable which we can change, when we then give it a singleton type, i.e. an type which has only a single instance. So, we can re-assign `in` as often as we want, but we can only assign the same thing to it. That's illogical. (Well, technically, we could also assign `null` to it.)

And in fact, we want to be able to assign something to it, but also know whether we assigned something to it or not. That's why we use an `Option` in this case, and initialize it with `None`. So, re-interpret `None` as an `Option`, so that Scala infers the correct type:

```
var in = None: Option[FileInputStream]
```